# Where is TColor defined in Emgu OpenCV .Net wrapper?

Tags: c#, .net, image, emgucv

I am trying to create and Emgu `Image<TColor, TDepth>` and cannot seem to correctly specify the `TColor` for my image. So far I have loaded my image from a file into a .Net `Image`. I am now trying to do the following to convert that image to an OpenCV image representation.

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> cvTestImage = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(new Bitmap(testImage));
```

In Visual Studio both `Bgr`'s are underlined in red, though it seems to accept the `Byte` parameters (But I would assume that I need to use the OpenCV `TDepth` definitions?). Though the `Image<TColor, TDepth>` type is recognized and I have added `using Emgu.CV` and `using Emgu.Util` to my class.

I have searched the Emgu documentation website and found the documentation for both [`ColorType`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.4.0.0/html/561c7c68-fa5e-6bd9-b29c-2f8c7fd41b08.htm) and [`Bgr`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.4.0.0/html/f6682fa1-90bf-e2b0-50d5-084e3e8d1307.htm) but I cannot get my IDE to recognize either or find them in Emgu.

I have Emgu version 2.4.10.

From what I can tell from the documentation the type `Bgr` is located at `Emgu.CV.Bgr` but Visual Studio will not autocomplete to it. Also when I mouse over the `Byte` parameter to `Image<>` Visual Studio shows that it is of type `System.Byte` and not something like `Emgu.CV.TDepth.Byte`.

If it helps here is a view from Visual Studio

[image]

**EDIT:** Ok I am not sure what is going on now...

I am not sure if this issue started happened before or after I tried to install the [MVSCRT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13523) as recommended by the [Emgu documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.). But now when I try to call code from the Emgu library I receive the following error.

[image]

I have reinstalled the Emgu library along with reinstalling the MVSCRT. Whenever I try to call any Emgu code this exception is thrown. I am not sure where to go from here..

**EDIT2:**

I am not sure why but by removing the `using Emgu.Util` statement from the code the issue above has solved itself. It would be interesting to know what happened..

So I am now back the the semi-original issue.
[image]

I have installed the MSVCRT [as instructed](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.) by the Emgu website. 
[image]

**EDIT3:**

It looks like I finally got it working by moving the x86 and x64 directories to the execution folder. Now I am just waiting for the call to the function to return...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using EmguCV version 2.4 or 3.0, then don't forget this:

```
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
```

You can right-click on the unresolved `Bgr` token in Visual Studio and select **Resolve** in the context menu. You should see two menu items:

- using Emgu.CV.Structure;
- Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr

Select the first one to let Visual Studio extend your usings with the proposed one.

Comment: Hmm, the only issue I am having now when running is that  get a TypeInitializationException when trying to create the first `Image<>` which I assume is because I am using `System.Byte` and not something like `Emgu.CV.Byte`. Using Resolve would be a nice trick (thanks for that) but because Visual Studio recognizes it I cannot. Any idea where it might be located? // I am going to try to change `Byte` to something it won't recognize and use Resolve hopefully.

Comment: @KDecker, this exception has nothing to do with the `byte` type. You're missing the OpenCV dll's. Please read [this](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.).

Comment: My exception is specifically `An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll`. Which does not refer to the `Emgu.CV.CvInvoke` as in the page. (Though I did install the MSVCRT for my computer (It installed with the Emgu install and I did it again just to be sure)).

Comment: Ahh, never mind the specific error is directly below the first sentence of what I quoted above. Though even after installing the MSVCRT I have the same issues, I have made an edit above.